SSIS Execute SQL Task not returning Result Set to string variable
Following YouTube example, but mine does not work. My Execute SQL Task is not assigning the selected string to User::FileName variable.



After building, tried to debug by right-click, Execute 'Get Excel file name' task. Is this the best way to debug?  I cannot run the whole thing because the User::FileName remains blank and get an error further down the code.
I expect 'PensacolaCitySales_' to be put in User:FileName but it remains blank.
The Progress tab shows that it executed:
Progress: Executing query "SELECT 'PensacolaCitySales_'". - 100 percent complete

sqlstatement should have been  select * from <TableName>

No table because want to base the filename on date.  Originally had "SELECT 'PensacolaCitySales_' + FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd')" but simplified it to get some kind of result.

In this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkSOBRaTq74
at 10:41, the User::FileName is already populated without executing the task or running the whole program.
There is something I'm missing, a setting or something that is not working the same.
